# Spring error "Required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I´m starting to work with Spring, and recently I wanted to implement a Generic Repository. I followed this tutorial (https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/) but I can´t make it work.

I keep getting "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.dani.demo.dao.GenericRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found." error and I can´t find any solution to this error. Hope you can help me.

GenericRepository:

```java
package com.dani.demo.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

}
```

GenericRepositoryImpl:

```java
package com.dani.demo.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager em;

    public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
    }

}
```

CervezaService:

```java
package com.dani.demo.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager em;

    public GenericRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
    }

}
```

CervezaServiceImpl:

```java
package com.dani.demo.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dani.demo.dao.GenericRepository;
import com.dani.demo.model.Cerveza;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CervezaServiceImpl implements CervezaService {

    @Autowired
    private GenericRepository<Cerveza, Integer> d;

    @Override
    public List<Cerveza> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return d.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Cerveza> get(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return d.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Cerveza c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        d.save(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Cerveza c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        d.save(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        d.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

and the error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.dani.demo.dao.GenericRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' in your configuration.
```

Also, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dani</groupId>
    <artifactId>02-CervezasCRUDGeneric</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>02-CervezasCRUDGeneric</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tablas_de_prueba?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= rtgd
spring.datasource.password= trgdtt


# ===============================
# = Tomcat configurations
# ===============================
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait= 20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active= 50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle= 20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle= 15

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

# ===============================
# = VIEW RESOLVER
# ===============================
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Comment: Your `GenericRepositoryImpl` should not be a component so remove the `@Repository` annotation like Simon mentions. Did you also put `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = GenericRepositoryImpl.class)` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You are not following the tutorial! If you do a tutorial please read it carefully.

GenericRepositoryImpl must not be a Spring Repository. Remove the annotation:

```
@Transactional
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {
```

Additionally you cannot inject the GenericRepository you have to create an interface that extends from it like in the tutorial with the TodoRepository

Comment: At first the Annotation was not there. I had another Repository class extending GenericRepositoryImpl with the @Repository annotation but I had the same error.

Comment: As I said please read the tutorial carefully and do every step as it is written

Comment: Even if I copy-paste the code, I get the same error.

Comment: And where is your BaseRepositoryFactoryBean?

Comment: `If you are using Spring Data JPA 1.9.X or newer, you can skip this step because creating the RepositoryFactoryBean is not mandatory anymore (you can still do it if you want to).`

Comment: Oh I see. There is another misunderstanding. You cannot use GenericRepository you have to create a interface that extends GenericRepository like in the tutorial TodoRepository

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that. I created CervezaRepository extending GenericRepository but the error was the same. `@Repository
public class CervezaRepository extends GenericRepositoryImpl<Cerveza, Integer> {

 public CervezaRepository(Class<Cerveza> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
  super(domainClass, em);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

}
`

Comment: No you have to create an interface not a class interface TodoRepository extends BaseRepository<Todo, Long>

Comment: Oh, I see. That was the error. I created both Interface and Class, but only the interface is necessary. Many thanks!